# Microsoft Remote Desktop cant wake W11 computer from sleep

Tags: networking, sleep, windows-11

Ive got a Desktop PC which i need to connect to from time to time using Microsoft Remote Desktop Mac MRD.

Sometimes i connect via LAN sometimes i connect over Dial In VPN to the router (which places me on the LAN).

Both the LAN and VPN to LAN access work fine, but if the computer goes to sleep you can not access it via MRD, the only way to access it is by going to the computer and waking it by moving the mouse. This is fine if you are physically near it eg. on the LAN locally. But can not be done if you are remote using the VPN to LAN.

Originally the Desktop PC was connected to the network via Wifi, which i though might be the problem so ive now turned off the wifi and used a wired ethernet connection instead. But i still have the same issue when the computer sleeps MRD cant wake it.

Ive tried setting the Wake On Lan settings in the config (see screenshot attached) but again to no avail.

My only work around currently is to set the PC to never sleep, but this isnt a long term solution.

Im running W11 Pro on a system with an ASUS motherboard.

Please see link here to view screenshots of my current network card / WOL setup in device manager - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mg6iP.jpg

Please see link to my current power settings here (note that these are reflective of the fact that i have set the computer to never sleep as a work around, but i do actually want it to sleep and just to be able to be woken) https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRFBf.jpg

Comment: Ethernet does not usually turn off to save power.  Check Sleep and make sure it is simple Suspend and not Hybrid Sleep which will move toward hibernation.

Comment: Thanks @John where can i set those settings. For the moment ive just set the computer to sleep never, but this isnt a great solution. Ive had a look at the sleep settings ive currently got see here https://imgur.com/a/oRNQNXy

Comment: Go to Control Panel, Power and Options.  Hybrid sleep (if supported) will be there.

Comment: Try in the network adapter's properties to enable these properties : " ARP (Address Resolution Protocol) offload" and "NS (Neighbor Solicitation) offload" ([link](https://www.energystar.gov/products/low_carbon_it_campaign/business_case/24_7_remote_access)). This combo is supposed to work as well as WOL. If that doesn't work for you, see if the router has an option to WOL a computer that is being contacted externally.

Comment: @John it seems all i have is there is balanced, power saver and high performance - https://imgur.com/a/8oSfY2b

Comment: You may need to leave the computer ON when you need it and turn the Monitor OFF when away to minimize power used.

Comment: @harrymc interesting article. Ive had a look and i have ARP Offload and NS offload both enabled. Re. the router we use does have a WOL feature, but for end users to access it , its probably too technical and will end up breaking something else.

Comment: You need to set the router's WOL only once for all users. The users don't need to do anything special.

Comment: What model is your router ?

Comment: @harrymc Draytek 2860

Answer (score 0):

My friend you have allowed the computer to turn off the device to save power which means that when there is no traffic the card will be disabled and may lose the magic packet. Also take a look in your power scheme of windows and disable any power saving features for network cards and the like. My work PC had the same issues and disabling the power saving fixed it. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The Draytek Vigor2860 supports Wake-On-Lan.

From the
[Draytek Vigor2860 Series User Manual page 233](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/837791/Draytek-Vigor2860-Series.html?page=233):

> A PC client on LAN can be woken up by the router it connects. When a
> user wants to wake up a specified PC through the router, he/she must
> type correct MAC address of the specified PC on this web page of Wake
> on LAN (WOL) of this router.
>
> In addition, such PC must have installed
> a network card supporting WOL function. By the way, WOL function must
> be set as "Enable" on the BIOS setting.

[image]

To find the MAC address of the network adapter, enter in the
Command Prompt (cmd) the command `ipconfig /all`. The address
will be found on the line labelled "Physical Address".

It's unclear from the manual whether WOL from outside the local network
is supported, or whether you will need to login to the router in order
to send the WOL request.
Even if the later case is the right one, this method still beats
physically going to the computer in order to move the mouse.

Comment: Thanks, as i understand that is using the router GUI to send to WOL command, rather than allowing other devices to send WOL packets around the LAN. The problem is i wouldnt want to give non admin users access to the router GUI.

Comment: It seems like it, but I would still try to set up the router for this PC, then send a WOL package to the router from outside the network, to see if it's transferred to the indicated PC.